# Canon ImageCLASS MF6580 prints blank

Tags: printer, toner

I found a discarded MF6580, which is printing blank sheets. I replaced the C106 toner cartridge in it, but it still prints blank. Is there anything else I can try, or is it just garbage?

Comment: If they discarded it, it is probably not worth fixing. Try the Canon service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking/repairing/replacing the Laser Shutter and its actuating arm.

> The laser shutter is a metal flap that covers the laser porthole when the cartridge is removed as a safety interlock. The porthole is a slit of about 1/2 by 3 inches in the back of the cartridge compartment (if you open the cartridge compartment, the front will be toward you.)
>
> The locking mechanism seems to wear out easily, and the laser shutter fails to open even with the cartridge is inserted. The problem sometimes goes away if you reinsert the cartridge, but eventually it becomes permanent.
>
> You can pry the flap open with a small screwdriver but do it at your own risk; the flap is a safety interlock to prevent the laser light from exiting the cartridge chamber when the cartridge is removed.

Example Laser Shutter arm picture:

[image]

Quote from here: [Canon ImageClass MF6580 prints blank pages](http://www.fixyourownprinter.com/forums/laser/64544)
More info/suggestions on dealing with a faulty shutter here: [Canon mf 6550 copy no print out its came out empty page](http://www.fixya.com/support/t572025-canon_mf_6550_copy_no_print_out_its_came)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the arm, but I wedged the shutter open with some rolled up paper, and now it's printing just fine.